Python PyTorch converting model from .pth to .pt
Getting issues below:
the model is not loading and I want to achieve the conversion from .pth to .pt
the code I'm using:
pth_file_path = '/content/sample_data/model_final.pth' 
pt_file_path = '/content/model.pt'


import torch
import torchvision
from unet import UNet 

model = UNet(3, 2)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(pth_file_path))
model.eval()
example = torch.rand(1, 3, 320, 480)
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, example)
traced_script_module.save(pt_file_path)

Error on below line:
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(pth_file_path))

The Error:
RuntimeError: PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive: failed finding central directory

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-42-63d953168a5b> in <cell line: 10>()
      8 
      9 model = UNet(3, 2)
---> 10 model.load_state_dict(torch.load(pth_file_path))
     11 model.eval()
     12 example = torch.rand(1, 3, 320, 480)

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py in __init__(self, name_or_buffer)
    454 class _open_zipfile_reader(_opener):
    455     def __init__(self, name_or_buffer) -> None:
--> 456         super().__init__(torch._C.PyTorchFileReader(name_or_buffer))
    457 
    458 

RuntimeError: PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive: failed finding central directory

could anyone know why it's causing that issue
